# Send email with node JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, email

I'm looking for a way to send mail with node js. My mail has html content that needs to be styled (I need to set the font-family and the color). I also need to put a image for the logo.

I already tried to use nodemailer but when I try to style my content it doesn't work, when I also try to link an image (for the logo) it doesn't work. Does anyone have an issue ?

If you have an other way than node mailer please tell me.

https://nodemailer.com/

Comment: Try mailgun.com if you're fine with third party.

Comment: Thank you, do you have a snippet where you add image and style ?

Comment: You can check out their API's they've a lot in Store. If you feel, the comment answers your question, please let me know so that I can post it as an answer.

Comment: You can use AWS SES for sending mail

Answer (score 3):

Checkout mailgun:

https://github.com/bojand/mailgun-js

It's really easy to setup and use! Here's a snippet from their documentation:

```
var filepath = path.join(__dirname, 'mailgun_logo.png');
var file = fs.readFileSync(filepath);

var data = {
  from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
  to: 'serobnic@mail.ru',
  subject: 'Hello',
  text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!',
  attachment: file
};

mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

You can do a lot with the package, includes the ability to attach files!

Answer (score 1):

Email client support for CSS styles [varies](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). In particular, many clients do not allow you to put styles into a css block; they must be inline directly with the elements. You can use something like [juice](https://github.com/Automattic/juice) to process your html to inline the styles.